# NSDate give me the error date, Anybody know why?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";

NSLog(@"Original Time:%@", _created_at);
NSDate *newCreatedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_created_at];

NSString *newString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newCreatedDate];
NSLog(@"Conversion Time:%@", newString);
```

This is the result:

> Original Time:Sun **Oct** 25 18:37:03 +0800 2015
>   Conversion Time:Sun **Jan** 25 18:37:03 +0800 2015

Comment: what should be intended result?

Comment: Also, what is the content of the string `_created_at`?

Comment: To clarify because the OP is not clear enough: he reads in `Sun Oct 25 18:37:03 +0800 2015`, converts it to a date and then outputs that date again, which results in `Sun Jan 25 18:37:03 +0800 2015` - Note the wrong month.

Comment: What's the value of `_created_at`. Your code shouldn't give this result since you keep the same `dateFormat`. But, since October is the 10th month, and January the first one, I think that there is something with 01 and 10 as a month which could be in `_created_at` or something like this and the value of `newCreatedDate`.

Comment: Please find the specs for date format strings and read up on what "D" means (vs "d").

Answer (score 1):

You should be using dd instead of DD.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
```

Comment: Thanks！   My mistake.